# Does assigning a variable to a method/function run it every time it's called?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make sure I'm building this code as efficiently as possible, but one questions keeps lingering: When I assign a variable to a method, am I slowing down the code every time it's called?

My Example:
(Yes, I'm technically using Google Apps Script, not JS, but I think the question applies to both)

Let's say I want to display the Subject of every Message in every Thread in my Gmail inbox 5 times (for some reason). Here's how I'd see that:

```js
function myFunction(){
  let allThreads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();

  var text = "";
  
  for(let x = 0 ; x < allThreads.length ; x++){
    let thisThread = x;

    let allMessages = thisThread.getMessages();

    for(let y = 0 ; y < allMessages.length ; y++){
      let thisMessage = y;

      let thisSubject = thisMessage.getSubject();

      let someNumber = 5;

      for( let z = 0; z < someNumber ; z++){
        text += " " + thisSubject;
      }
    }
  }

  Logger.log(text);
}
```

So, the actual question (finally): Am I calling the `getSubject()` method EVERY time I'm using the "thisSubject" variable?

Or even worse; Am I running

```js
GmailApp.getInboxThreads()[x].getMessages()[y].getSubject()
```

every time?

I'm barely a programmer, but would converting it to a string, rather than a reference to a method (or function) make the code run faster? Especially if we're talking referencing it 1,000 times instead of 5.

for example:

```js
//Replace

let thisSubject = thisMessage.getSubject();

//With

let thisSubject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(thisMessage.getSubject()));
```

Then, if we're expanding on that, would finding a way to `Stringify` only the necessary parts of even `GmailApp.getInboxThreads` be logical?

To throw another example out there for clarity; If I'm calling Google's SpreadsheetApp to get a sheet name such as:

```js
let mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abc123xyz');
let mySheets = mySpreadsheet.getSheets();
let thisSheet = mySheets[1];
let sheetName = thisSheet.getName();
```

Am I killing my code each time I use `sheetName` by re-opening the spreadsheet, getting all the sheets in it, picking out the 2nd then pulling it's name all over again?

Or am I cacheing(cache-ing?) an instance of each result of the methods and pulling from them instead?

Comment: It runs the function every time the assignment occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I calling the `getSubject()` method EVERY time I'm using the "thisSubject" variable?

No. In the inner loop (that runs `allThreads.length * allMessages.length` tiems), you call it *once*, on the line:

```
let allMessages = thisThread.getMessages();
```

The line initializes a variable named `allMessages` and has it point to an array in memory. Elsewhere when `allMessages` is referenced, that existing array is looked up.

Note that you probably have a bug here:

```
for(let y = 0 ; y < allMessages.length ; y++){
  let thisMessage = y;
  let thisSubject = thisMessage.getSubject();
```

You probably meant to do

```
for(let y = 0 ; y < allMessages.length ; y++){
  let thisMessage = allMessages[y];
  let thisSubject = thisMessage.getSubject();
```

or, even better, don't mess with indicies at all, and use iterators and `const`:

```
for (const thisMessage of allMessages) {
  const thisSubject = thisMessage.getSubject();
  // ...
```

---

> Am I killing my code each time I use sheetName by re-opening the spreadsheet, getting all the sheets in it, picking out the 2nd then pulling it's name all over again?

No - `.getName()` only runs once, and puts its result into memory, and `sheetName` is a variable that points to that value in memory. Further references to `sheetName` are trivial lookups to the existing value in memory.

> Or am I cacheing(cache-ing?) an instance of each result of the methods and pulling from them instead?

That's right.

---

In general, caching function call results can be useful. For example, it's better to avoid:

```
for (const value of someArray) {
  const someOtherValue = getSomeValue();
  // more loop body...
```

Because `someOtherValue` doesn't depend on what's being iterated over, you could do

```
const someOtherValue = getSomeValue();
for (const value of someArray) {
  // more loop body...
```

and avoid the repeated calls of `getSomeValue`. But you aren't making such a mistake anywhere in your code; don't worry.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! This was EXACTLY what I have been trying to find. And yes, the = y and = x lines were definitely a typo in my haste (amusingly from using for/of's lately). I feel like there are a lot of cases where the index is extention helpful, but I've been run to move to for/of whenever I can.